# How to create Facebook-type experience on a Linux server

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

I have a client that wants to create a Facebook-like experience on her website (obviously significantly less sophisticated), where she wants users to have:

1. Profiles (with personal information, and a few custom text
   fields)
2. Be able to private messages, and
3. Be able to group chat about specific subjects (aka like facebook pages, or forums
   with short messages)

She is running a Linux server with Ruby on Rails.

Any ideas on the appropriate technology to use? I'm thinking XMPP could do a lot of this, but maybe you guys have a better idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered an out of the box application such as Social Engine? It's a fairly reasonable price and you can try it free for 30 days. http://www.socialengine.net/

Comment: Or have a look at Elgg, http://elgg.org.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_social_networking_softwaren also has a couple of rails options, if you want to stick with what's there already.

Comment: She only has Ruby on Rails? If the server is capable of that, it should be capable of PHP which opens up the ability to use - http://buddypress.org/ . Is it a VPS? Shared server? In-house?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has Ruby on Rails. Rails is perfectly suitable to do such an application in no time. Just create a User model with Devise and some Message models

Comment: Devise sounds like a great idea! I read through the docs but can't find whether it can store extra information about the user. We would need to store a user's picture, name, email, occupation, etc. Is this built in to Devise or would we have to create the functionality ourselves? (or do you know another solution to do this easily?)

Comment: there may be some plugin to do that but quite honestly, Rails makes it very easy for you to do so. just add the properties to the model and you are good to go

Comment: even with images? lol damn you're very good at selling ruby on rails as a language (i actually just bought a book to start learning it), something like this would take days in asp.net

Comment: yes, even with images. rails is really perfect for those kind of applications